# memory footprints for hash_map seems less that unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map, g++4.9

I am using g++ 4.9.2 on Solaris 10, and when I migrated from using g++ 2.95.3 I had to change hash_map to unordered_map. But, it seems that unordered_map has some performance bottlenecks compared to earlier hash_map. After use when I use rehash(0) on an unordered_map, it seems not to return my used memory in the free pool. How can I use my old hash_map using g++ 4.9.2?